# creating dynamic web project in eclipse

Tags: html

Can anyone help me in knowing how to create a Dynamic web project using HTML 5 in eclipse? I'm looking for simple login application which uses HTML 5 for User Interface, Spring MVC and Hibernate.

Any links or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start at the [Getting started with spring](http://www.springsource.org/get-started) page. If you haven't already, I'd recommend downloading the [Spring Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.org/sts), or at least the eclipse plugin. There are plenty of samples and tutorials to get you started. As for the HTML5 part, just make sure that templating language that you choose for the view layer supports it, but ultimately that will be on you to follow the HTML5 specs.